# How do I test whether a Django QuerySet method was called?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, python-unittest

Say I have the following:

`models.py`:

```py
class FooQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def bar(self):
        return self.filter(...)


class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(FooQuerySet)
```

`views.py`:

```py
class FooListView(ListView):
    model = Foo

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        return qs.bar()
```

And I wish to test that `models.FooQuerySet.bar` is called when the view is called.

So far I have:

```py
request = RequestFactory().get('')
view = FooListView.as_view()

with mock.patch('<best_guess>') as mocked:
    mocked.return_value = Foo.objects.none()
    view(request)
    mocked.assert_called_once()
```

Where `<best_guess>` has been:

- `foo_app.models.FooQuerySet.bar`
- `foo_app.models.Foo.objects.bar`
- `foo_app.views.Foo.objects.bar`

None of which worked.  Even if I happened upon a magic patch string that *did* work, I fear I simply don't understand what's going on here.  What's the *correct* way to test that `FooQuerySet.bar()` is called?

(There's also the added difficulty that QuerySets are chained, so I might one day need to know if `FooQuerySet.any().amount().of().weird().methods().bar()` is called).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to mock the `ListView.get_queryset` and leave it as the `MagicMock`, e.g.:

```
with mock.patch("foo_app.views.ListView.get_queryset") as mocked:
    view(request)
    mocked.bar.assert_called_once()
```

And then for your long chains of callbacks, just use:

```
mocked.bar.return_value.any.return_value.amount.return_value.of.assert_called_once()
...
```

However remember, that if the view is dependant on the QuerySet being returned, it may raise some errors when presented with MagicMock instance instead.

Comment: That snippet only seems to work if I set `mocked.return_value = mocked` within the `with` block...  Which I'd expect to make the chain work flawlessly, but doesn't.  Essentially what I'm trying to test is that `bar()` is called once, where in the chain doesn't really matter.